# Toolbar and XMLHttpRequest status = 0

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xmlhttprequest

I am developing a Firefox toolbar with a single button that when clicked retrive links from current page with same domain and respecting "**[Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)**".

So lets say we are on a page like http://example.com/ it will extract links like http://example.com/some-other-page

And all this is currently working.

My problem is that once I get all links I want my extension to make an `XMLHttpRequest` to retrieve the title of linked page.

But when I attempt to do so i get a response status = 0.

Here is what I am doing:

```js
for(var j=0;j<numLinks;j++){
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  alert(linksHref[j]);
  request.open('GET', linksHref[j], true);
  request.send();
  alert(request.status);
  if (request.status === 200) {
    ...
  }
}
```

But it never gets response status 200.

What's wrong with this code?

I found in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131096/ff-extension-getting-xmlhttp-status-0) that Request module is suggested. I tried it but doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using Add-on SDK/content scripts?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide an onload event for your request:

```
request.onload = function()
{

   // What you want to happen
   if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200)
   {

       // Success!

   }

}
```